# How do I call an operator overload method inside my static method?

Tags: python, class, object, magic-methods

I'm slowly teaching myself **Classes** in Python and have hit a brick wall. I could desperately use some help.

I have created the base class, **Number**, and would like to figure out how to do two things:

1. Overload the function of `addition()` of the class `Number` through the child class `Rational(Number)`, and update the object from which it is called
2. Create a static method `addition` that calls the overload function in its return statement and serves as a method override of its parent class

I've managed to write the following lines of code:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def addition(self, other_rational_num):
        pass

class Rational(Number):
    def __init__(self, p, q, number):
        super().__init__(number)
        self.__p = p
        self.__q = q

    def __add__(self, other_rational_num):
        number = self.number + other_rational_num.number
        return Number(number)

    @staticmethod
    def addition(number, other_rational_num):
        return Rational.__add__(number, other_rational_num)
```

If I type the basic operation in the static method's return statement `return number + other_rational_num`, I don't get an error. But how can I leverage the overload method I already created?

Any support is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Why is it a static method?  Why not just:

```
    def addition(self, other_rational_num):
        return self.__add__(other_rational_num)
```

And do you really want a Rational plus a Rational to return a Number?  That seems odd.